# How to proper set viewport for mobile with Vue and Vuetify? Viewport not fit fullscreen of phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

everyone. I have stange render behaviour with vue + vuetify. When i using chore and change size in desktop everytinh is ok. But when i use phone chrome.I received render bug (render only yellow and page content take 30% of page in the top left corner but footer render ok) Can send any additional code if needed. How to fix pagecontent to fit screen.

Possible problems with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

When i take responsive in development tools (chrome or firefox) everything is ok, when i change to some phone Samsung iPhone , i receive render like in screenshot below.

[image]

mine Base.vue code

```
    <template>
  <v-app style="background-color: #EEEEEE">
    <v-container v-if="pageLoading" fluid>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center">
        <dot-loader :loading="pageLoading" color="#0000FF" size="100px"></dot-loader>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
    <div v-else>
      <Header/>
      <notifications group="global" position="top center"/>
      <v-main class="mt-4">
        <v-container fluid class="mt-0 pt-0">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

import Header from '@/components/base/Header'
import DotLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/DotLoader.vue'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Footer from './components/base/Footer'

export default {
  name: 'Base',
  components: {
    Footer,
    Header,
    DotLoader
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('base', ['pageLoading'])
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.$store.commit('base/DRAWER', true)
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Code tha render in router-view

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col lg="9" md="9" cols="12">
      <v-row>
        <v-col lg="6" md="6" cols="12">
          <v-card :loading="componentLoading" shaped>
            
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col lg="6" md="6" cols="12">
          <v-card shaped :loading="componentLoading">
            
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
    <v-col lg="3" md="3" cols="12">
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-card shaped :loading="componentLoading">
            
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import InstitutionSelect from '@/components/base/InstitutionSelect'
import GradeTeamSelect from '@/components/base/GradeTeamSelect'

export default {
  name: 'StaffDashboard',
  components: { InstitutionSelect, GradeTeamSelect },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('base', ['colors', 'componentLoading', 'adminStaff']),
 some other js code not related to display features
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Big thanks for help.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I assume you expect "PAGE CONTENT" to fit the whole screen. This looks like a `css` problem to me, unrelated to `vue`.

Comment: Page content go not to full phone screen but only to left top corner. But footer render ok,

Comment: I didn't use css only build in vuetify feature. And if i use the same screen size ob desktop chrome/firefox everything is ok.

Comment: @Beliaf `vuetify` uses css. Could you provide the code of the component which is loaded in `<router-view></router-view>` on your screenshot?

Comment: @StevenSiebert provided except of js logic that not related to display features.

Answer (score -1):

I was right problem was in `<meta name="viewport"`

For me helped to set up next `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">` So i added `user-scalable=no` to viewport.